# Dictionary thesaurus replacing substrings

Tags: string, list, dictionary, replace

So I have a dictionary that contains words and their synonyms. The purpose is to  replace substrings in a string with a random synonym. Here's my code.

```
import random
thesaurus = {
              "happy":["glad",  "blissful", "ecstatic", "at ease"],
              "sad"  :["bleak", "blue",     "depressed"]
            }
phrase = input("Enter a phrase: ")
for x in phrase.split():

    if x in thesaurus:
        ran = len(thesaurus[x])
        print( len(thesaurus[x]))
        ranlis = random.randint(0,ran - 1)
        phrase = phrase.replace(x,str.upper(thesaurus[x][ranlis]))
print(phrase)
```

If I input "happy happy happy"
The output is:

```
ECSTATIC ECSTATIC ECSTATIC
```

I want it to print a different synonym each time(or at least be able to. I understand that it is random).
So:

ECSTATIC BLISSFUL AT EASE

I understand the error in my logic but am unsure how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

The key is to replace only one occurrence. The replace() function takes 3 parameters, the third being the number of occurrences you want to replace.
So:

```
phrase = phrase.replace(x,str.upper(thesaurus[x][ranlis]),1)
```